# Do SQLite callback functions have one or two parameters?

Tags: javascript, sqlite, function, parameters, callback

Do SQLite callback functions have one or two parameters?

I've seen many examples of these functions, and some have one, two or even no parameters. Take the following example:

```
db.executeSql(
    'SELECT count(*) AS mycount FROM mytable;",
    [],
    function(dx, resultSet) {
        // resultSet.rows.item(0).mycount
    },
    function(dx, err) {
        // err.message
    }
);
```

In both the success and failure callback functions, `dx` is presumed to be a handle for the database connection. But I have seen examples that omit this and only pass `resultSet` and `err` respectively. In other words:

```
function(resultSet) {
```

and

```
function(err) {
```

and some examples that have no parameters sent to the success callback.

Which is the correct way of specifying parameters to these functions?

Comment: I'd guess all the ways are correct. You should check the docs for sure.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, after some closer looking for what seemed like ages, I've come to the conclusion that the callback functions only have an additional parameter when the query is enclosed in a transaction.

So for just the query, you would do this :

```
db.executeSql(
    'SELECT count(*) AS mycount FROM mytable;",
    [],
    function(resultSet) {
        // resultSet.rows.item(0).mycount
    },
    function(err) {
        // err.message
    }
);
```

But if you're using a transaction approach, it would be this :

```
db.transaction(function(tx) {
    db.executeSql(
        'SELECT count(*) AS mycount FROM mytable;",
        [],
        function(tx, resultSet) {
            // resultSet.rows.item(0).mycount
        },
        function(tx, err) {
            // err.message
        }
    );
});
```

I haven't been able to find this explained in any of the documentation or in any examples, but when you look at any examples where a transaction is used, they always have the extra parameter in the callback functions, so I'm just assuming this is the correct usage.

Any thoughts?